# Processing error: Possible error on variable assignment near ‘mainGame=’

Tags: java, processing

I wrote a gameand used the following code

```
class Gameboard {
  int gameWidth;
  int gameHeight;
  int[][] gameBoard;
  public Gameboard(int w, int h){
    this.gameWidth = w;
    this.gameHeight = h;
    int[][] gameBoard = new int[w][h];
  }

}

int totalMines;


boolean firstPlay;


boolean gameWin;



int lossX, lossY;

mainGame = new Gameboard(30,16);
void setup()
{
    size(600,360);
    ellipseMode(CENTER);
    rectMode(CORNER);
    textSize(14);
    totalMines = 0;
    lossX = -1;
    lossY = -1;
    gameWin = false;
    mainGame.generateMines();
}


void draw()
{
    
}
```

and as I am trying to run the game with setup like this:

Processing gives me error saying" Possible error on variable assignment near ‘mainGame=’"

If I reverse the order of mainGame= and setup, the error becomes "Missing operator, semicolon, or ‘}’ near ‘setup’?" Can someone help me on this?

Edit: This is the whole code that I made following a tutorial, and based on comments I have tried to insert mainGame=new Gameboard into setup() but it won't work.

Comment: I don't know anything about Processing, but in Java, a line of code like `mainGame = new Gameboard(25,25);` must be either inside a method, or inside a constructor, or part of an initialiser (so you could declare `private mainGame = new Gameboard(25,25);` for example).

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but it seems that adding a "private" does not help, the same error still appears

Comment: Please read the tag wikis for the tags that you use.  Specifically, the `[computer-science]` tag wiki says: "Computer science (CS) is the science behind programming. *Use for questions related to the more theoretical questions involving programming.*".  I'm sure that you will agree that there is nothing theoretical in the question you asked.  (I have removed it.)

Comment: The other problem is that your example is too fragmentary for us to be sure that we understand your question ... and for us to give a clear answer that **you** can understand.  Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: FWIW - I think that Dawood's diagnosis is correct.  But you have misinterpreted his suggestion.  It is not a *complete* fix ... or necessarily even the *correct* fix.  This is implied when he says "for example"!! Unfortunately, we can't tell you the correct fix without more information; see above.

Comment: No, my suggestion had a typo (and it's too late to change it now).  I meant to write `private Gameboard mainGame =  new Gameboard(25, 25);` - but what I was trying to say was, make this an initialiser, not just an assignment.

Comment: Sorry for wrong tags, I have edited my codes on the above, with the word limitation I deleted the minesweeper rules part but saved the problematic part. I tried Dawood's method but it seems the problem changes to null pointer exception.And also apologize for the poor understanding, Im still new to Processing and just began using it for a week

Comment: As  general rule - if making a change looks like it changed one problem into another, it means that you had two problems initially, and you fixed just one of them.

Comment: Really the only thing that was missing was a type for `mainGame`. You never said what object type it has, so you can't assign anything to it. `Gameboard mainGame = ...` solves the error you're getting, because it's 100% correct: there is a glaring error near `mainGame = ...` =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processing is a java based language: https://processing.org

The following re-arrangement of your code should run without error:

```
class Gameboard {
  int gameWidth;
  int gameHeight;
  int[][] gameBoard;

  Gameboard(int w, int h) {
    gameWidth = w;
    gameHeight = h;
    int[][] gameBoard = new int[w][h];
  }
  
  void generateMines(){
    
  }
}

Gameboard mainGame;

  int totalMines = 0;
  int lossX = -1;
  int lossY = -1;
  boolean gameWin = false;
  
void setup() {
  size(600, 360);
  ellipseMode(CENTER);
  rectMode(CORNER);
  textSize(14);
  mainGame = new Gameboard(25, 25);
  // initiate the board by rolling the mines randomly.
  mainGame.generateMines();
}

void draw(){
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I made changes according to your answer and strangely there is still nullpointer exception. I checked through all other methods and they seems all initialized somehow.

Comment: I deleted all other parts and the code now works fine!! Thanks for the help, I am now troubleshooting on other parts

Comment: Sure, let me find out how to do that

Comment: Note that the reason this works is that you didn't just rearrange it, you also changed to to actually _solve_ the original problem: you turned it from `mainGame` into `Gameboard mainGame`, which is what the error was about. You can't have untyped variables in Processing.